# Django add dropdown filter for a view with no class / model

Tags: python, django, filter, view, dropdown

I have a method mapped to a url in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mydir/statistics', statistics_view, name="Statistics")
]
```

Then in `mydir/statistics/views.py` I have the method:

```
def statistics_view(request):
    list_mystuff = Mytable.objects.all() #Mytable is defined in models
    ....
    #lots of code here to assign "enriched_models" data structure
    enriched_models = {bunch of stuff}
    ......
    return render(request, 'statistics.html', {"statistics_enriched_models": enriched_models})
```

It all works fine and everything is rendered in using `statistics.html` template.

Now I need to implement a dropdown filter by one of the fields of Mytable. 
With classes I would have to create class for Statistics in models.py, StatisticsAdmin as a proxy model in `admin.py`, register them both, and have 
`list_filter=["myfield",]` set in StatisticsAdmin

Is there a way to set up a dropdown filter (with list_filters or whatever)  and have the dropdown rendered directly without creating the classes, just with what I already have (a method that populates the template)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. You do have a model class: Mytable. But if you want a dropdown, why don't you create a form?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Maybe I should, but everything in this app is done either by url->method->template way or just a class that represents a table directly one-to-one. There are no forms. None of the fields in my view table (what I show on the screen) exist in the DB, they are all calculated and assigned in the statistics_view method. "Mytable" data is used for those calculations but are not displayed. Will "form" approach work for that?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

At the end I used django-filter tool: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

The filter to use for the dropdown control is django_filters.ChoiceFilter .
Worked fine.